# How can I read OPUS packets one by one from ogg/opus file

Tags: codec, ogg, opus

I need to read OPUS packets one by one from ogg/opus file and send them further in OPUS format so without decoding. I'm looking at [opusfile](https://opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.12/index.html) lib but API and examples are rather complicated and more focused on decoding the file and getting resulted PCM. Is there a way to achieve what I want with this lib and how? If not what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I am slightly late. I had very similar use case, I wanted to extract opus packets from ogg opus file. I found this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285277/10110652

Following code will help you to get opus packets (without been decoded to pcm) in 'nextPacket' byteArray inside while loop

```
File audioFile = null; 
    try {
        audioFile = new File("xyz.ogg"); //input ogg opus file
        oggFile = new FileStream(new RandomAccessFile(audioFile, "r"));

        for (LogicalOggStream stream : (Collection<LogicalOggStream>) oggFile.getLogicalStreams()) {
            byte[] nextPacket = stream.getNextOggPacket();
            while (nextPacket != null) {
                    //nextPacket here contains opus packet
                    //do what ever you want to do with this packet
                 
                nextPacket = stream.getNextOggPacket();
            }
        }

    } catch (EndOfOggStreamException e) {
        System.out.println("End of File");
        //file usually get over by raising this exception while execution getNextOggPacket()
    }
```

Same program can be used to extract vorbis encoded packets in ogg container, means ogg vorbis file.

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

[libogg](https://xiph.org/ogg/doc/libogg/) could be used to parse the Ogg Opus file's "pages", and then the opus "packets" could then be extracted from those pages.  Mind that packets *may* span across pages, but I have personally not come across that when testing files created by [opusenc](https://opus-codec.org/docs/opus-tools/opusenc.html).  You could also parse the pages manually (see [Splitting an Ogg Opus File stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274671/splitting-an-ogg-opus-file-stream/59278350#59278350))

I recommend reading the basics of the Opus File Spec (**RFC 7845**) to understand the file structure first. https://opus-codec.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`libogg`](https://xiph.org/ogg/) to get access to the Opus packets. It's not all that much simpler than `opusfile` unfortunately. In C-ish pseudocode, the general flow is:

```
readPage(ogg_sync_state* syncState, ogg_page* page, file) {
  while ((ogg_sync_pageout(syncState, page) != 1) && file is good) {
    buffer = ogg_sync_buffer(syncState, yourMaxReadSize);
    bytesActuallyRead = read(file, buffer, yourMaxReadSize);
    ogg_sync_wrote(syncState, bytesActuallyReadFromFile); //tell the syncState how many bytes were actually read
  } //now we have a page, or the file is done
}

read() {
  ogg_sync_state oggSyncState;
  ogg_stream_state oggStreamState;
  ogg_page oggPage;
  ogg_packet oggPacket;

  open file;

  while (file is good) {
    readPage(&oggSyncState, &oggPage);
    if (ogg_page_bos(&oggPage)) {
      sn = ogg_page_serialno(&oggPage); //you can remember this serial number and check it on every page for robustness
      ogg_stream_init(&oggStreamState, sn);
    } 
    ogg_stream_pagein(&oggStreamState, &oggPage);
    while (ogg_stream_packetout(&oggStreamState, &oggPacket) != 0) {
      //check if it's a header packet, skip if so.
      //See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7845.html#section-5 to see how to identify a header packet
      //Else it must be data
      do something with the buffer oggPacket.packet with size oggPacket.bytes
    }
    readPage(&oggSyncState, &oggPage, file);
    ogg_stream_pagein(&oggStreamState, &oggPage_);
  }
}
```

`readPage` pulls a bunch of bytes (`yourMaxReadSize`) from the file into the `oggSyncState` structure, and then extracts pages one by one. In `read`, packets are extracted from the pages one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking about `libogg` but had a hope there is easier way with less code using `opusfile`